# CRT on a history tracking fields

Tags: custom-report-type, custom-reports

I have a custom object for which history tracking is enabled. I want to creatr a custom report type for those history tracking fields.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a custom report type for history tracking fields/object. Its only available as standard report type.

Can Upvote for this idea:
https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000Br1wAAC

Comment: But is there any kind of workaround for that.

Comment: Workaround depends upon your condition/scenario. What is your need? Please explain

Comment: You can create a VF page to display your data as you desire

Comment: I got a history tracking in a custom object, I need to display the record updating user's role, profile and other use details so I need this report type.

Comment: Please suggest a no-code solution.

Comment: I am not sure, but you can try creating a Joined report with your current report and a User Table and summarize with record owner/updating user name and in another report, you can display required user details.